# How to use First Method in querying data with Entity Datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .Include("Clients")
    .GroupBy(i => i.Clients.ClientName)
    .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(it => it.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault());
```

I want to get only the last order made by each client. The basis for the code I got from here [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq), from Freddy's answer. (I'm including "Clients" because Orders has ClientId but not client name and the results are to be displayed in a grid including the client name which I'm getting from Clients).
This works properly.

**MY QUESTION:**

Is it possible to do this using an asp.net Entity Datasource control?
Is it possible to use FirstOrDefault in some way in the asp.net Entity Datasource control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use the `EntityDataSource`'s `QueryCreated` event as demonstrated in [Filter with EntityDatasource in ASP.NET webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194650/filter-with-entitydatasource-in-asp-net-webforms) in the question and answers.

In the case of this question I  wrote

```
protected void EntityDataSource1_QueryCreated(object sender, QueryCreatedEventArgs e)
{
   var ordersQuery = e.Query.OfType<Orders>();
   e.Query = ordersQuery.Include("Clients")
   .GroupBy(i => i.Clients.ClientName)
   .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(it => it.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `Include` to the end of the query ...

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .GroupBy(i => i.Clients.ClientName)
    .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(it => it.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Include("Clients");
```

... you'll get `Order`s with their clients included.

With the original `Include` the query shape changes after the `Include` was applied. [This always makes `Include` ineffective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29308569/861716). You can move it to the end of the query, because even after the grouping, the query still return `Order`s, so the `Include` is applicable.

Note however that this is a tremendous overkill. Entire `Client` records are queried from the database, entire `Client` objects are materialized and in the end you only display their names. It's much better to project the required data to a DTO that exactly contains the data you want to display. For example:

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .GroupBy(i => i.Clients.ClientName)
    .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(it => it.OrderDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(o => new OrderDto
                 {
                     o.OrderNumber,
                     o. ... // More Order properties
                     Client = o.Clients.Name
                 });
```

The DTO should be a class containing these properties.

I don't know the Entity Datasource control. From what I see in the MSDN documentation it seems too restricted to even shape the query sufficiently to get the last orders of each client. And it expects an entity set, no DTOs.

Comment: 1. What's the difference between putting the Include at the beginning or the end? 2. Of Include("Clients") is at the end will that not cause a problem with GroupBy(i => i.Clients.ClientName) at the beginning? 3. What is "to project the required data to a DTO" in this context and how is it done? 4. The question I asked is how to execute this query with an ASP.NET Entity Datasource control.

Comment: Thank you! I tried placing the include at the end of the query as you suggested and that raised a compiler error: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyProject.DAL.Orders>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyProject.DAL.Orders>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try `using System.Data.Entity`. Did you use the lambda version of Include?

Comment: using System.Data.Entity doesn't help. What's the lamda version of Include?

Comment: `Include(o => o.Clients)`. I don't understand why `Include` at the end raises this exception. `context.Orders` is also `IQueryable<Orders>`, so it shouldn't make a difference for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `OrderbyDescending` try using the `max` operated as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14981037/1735196)

Comment: Interesting idea! Will this improve performance? In any event I have no problem with my query, my question is how to execute this query with an ASP.NET Entity Datasource control.

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164503/entitydatasource-orderby-conflict) that with the EntityDataSource you can use:

```
Select="top(1) it.[OrderDate]"
```

However if you want to `Order by DESC` the `top` will be executed before the `Order by DESC`.
If you want the `Order by` executed before the `top`, in other words to get the last Item, instead of `top` do this in Code behind:

```
protected void entityDataSource_Selecting(object sender,EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.SelectArguments.MaximumRows = 1;
}
```

All of this I got from that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164503/entitydatasource-orderby-conflict) in the Qustion and Answer.